# how rewrite urls without rooting to single file?

Tags: php, url, content-management-system, permalinks

i guess is not possible but it may exist a way that i don't know for pretty url, or url rewriting without rooting all requests on a single index.php page

on existing website with folder structure and url like

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/news/?id=123
```

is it possible to transform them in something like

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/news/myarticle
```

i can't find any solution to solve this without rewrite the code to root all request to a single index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you are already use index.php for all news: `/news/index.php`.

You can use for it standart `.htaccess` trick

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

And put it to `/news/.htaccess`. Every request on `/news/***` will lead to `/news/index.php`, but other folders will keep they behaviour.

Comment: i have a lot of different directories, like http://www.mywebsite.com/products/?idp=123 and so on. What you are saying is to get a different .htaccess in each one. And i still need to add a unique string id to identify the record

Comment: @al404, of course you need. User-friendly URLs has two stroies: generation urls and routing. .htaccess can help with routing, but useless for generation.